# Integral of a f(x,y)=xy over the circle with radius 2 oriented positively (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have to integrate $f(x,y) = xy$ over $|z| = 2$. I've worked out the integral using the fact that $x = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$ ending up with $f(z) = \frac{-i(z^2-\bar{z}^2)}{4}$  Now I define the parametrization $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ and finally I find that the value of this integral is zero. Here comes my question, shouldn't my integral be something different than zero? Because using the C-R equations I find that $f$ is only analytic at $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ and from what I've read and understand if $f$ is not analytic at every point on the inside of $\gamma$ then the integral should be different than zero. Can someone please help me with this question please?
Edit: Or I mean that If $f$ is analytic at all points interior to and on $\gamma$ then the integral over $\gamma$ is zero. But in this case I don't have that :( I'm quite confused.

Comment: You're confusing a theorem for its converse. The theorem is that "if analytic (in appropriate regions) then integral over closed paths is $0$". The converse is not true; i.e it is not true that "if not analytic (in appropriate regions) then integral is non-zero", and your example shows precisely that the converse is not true

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks for such quick response. I understand so I've shown that the converse of the theorem is not true. But now I remember why I said that. According to Cauchy's Integral formula, at least from what I understand, basically when you have a function that has a z value where the function is not analytic, for example 1/z and w=0 at say gamma a circle, then intuitively I would claim that since f is not analytic at w=0 then it's integral must be non-zero. In that case when can you say that a Integral is non-zero?

Comment: You need to follow the theorems carefully. The theorem is roughly that "if analytic then the integral over a closed path is $0$". If the hypothesis of this theorem is not fulfilled, then you can't make any conclusions (unless you have some other additional information), because anything can happen. In some cases the integral is $0$, in some cases it is not.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so there's really not theorem which would allow me to conclude, given some conditions, that a integral is different than zero?

Comment: I'm not saying that; all I'm saying is that you shouldn't hastily make such conclusions because they can be wrong (as your examples show). Off the top of my head, I can't think of any theorem which tells you when an integral is non-zero (though I may be missing something obvious, idk)

Comment: @peek-a-boo all right you've cleared my confusions thanks for your answers and your patience.

Comment: Anyway, the comments are correct.  $\displaystyle \oint_C f(z) \, dz = 0$ does not imply that $f(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere on and inside $C$.  For example, take $C$ to be your circle, and let $f(z) =1/z^2.$

Comment: @mjw nice I would try that example thanks for your answer :D

Comment: @mjw how do you get that for the real part? Isn't it $J:= \int_{|z|=2} xy \, dz = \int_{|z|=2} xy\,dx + i \int_{|z|=2} xy \, dy$, so plugging in $x=2\cos t, y = 2 \sin t$, we get $J= 8 \int_0^{2\pi}-\cos t \sin^2t \, dt + 8i \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2t \sin t \, dt = 0$?

Comment: @user580918.  You are right!  That's a mistake!